# Cross-Page Posting Without PostBackUrl

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is there a way to do cross-page posting without setting the PostBackUrl attribute or PostBackOptions to a control? I need a way to be able to dynamically change the action url on the client side.

Currently I am using form.action to post to another page, but this fails when I set EnableViewStateMac = "true". Microsoft's recent security updates requires this EnableViewStateMac setting: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/09/09/farewell-enableviewstatemac.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your best best is probably to POST back to a given Url but dynamically set a variable (hidden field value) on the client as to which page you really want to process the request. Then on the server do a Server.Transfer which will pass over the Request state to the other page.

[Server.Transfer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219294)

So you GET PageA, user fills in form and client side code sets hidden variable to PageA, PageB or PageC. Then you POST back to PageA which reads hidden field and if necessary does a Server.Transfer to PageB or PageC for "actual" processing.

Comment: Server.Transfer would keep the same URL though. I also need the URL to change.